# Параллельная запись в несколько БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть такая задача:

На проекте, написанном на фреймворке, надо прикрутить резервную БД по такому принципу: когда что-то пишется (удаляется) в базу - пишется сразу в обе (в ту, что была, и в ее клон).

Считывание, разумеется, происходит только с одной.

Как такое реализовать, не переписывая все запросы в коде?

(Единственное, что приходит в голову, - расковырять ядро фреймворка и в том месте, где он пишет в БД, добавить код, который будет во вторую писать.)

Есть ли какие-то альтернативные решения данного вопроса (например, на стороне хостера настройки какие, которые базу зеркалят и т.д.)?

Спасибо.

Comment: [основы репликации в MySQL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/56702/)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно обеспечить этот функционал на уровне БД для некоторых операций, можно воспользоваться триггерами. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Хотя грамотный подход к Вашей задаче состоит в кластеризации и репликации БД, но это достаточно сложно в настройке и администрировании.